# Align this video to right

Tags: wordpress, html

I want to align this :

```
<video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="video/supercoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

To paste it in wordpress text and embed it with a link to a page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
<video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay" style="float: right;">
<source src="video/supercoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

or

```
<div style="text-align:right;"><video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="video/supercoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```